# How to merge records based on similar attributes in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, merge

I work in ArcMap 10.8.1.

I have a feature class of ~40k records with ~20 attribute fields. I need to MERGE the records based on one of the field values like this:

Values sample: D1; D1_1; D2; D2_1, R43; R43_1; 12; 12_1; ...

Merging rule: D1 merge with D1_1; D2 merge with D2_1; R43 merge with R43_1; (each record x has its corresponding x_1 record)

Now, my manual approach would be this:

```
Start Edit Session
Select * where fieldname = 'D1' AND fieldname = 'D1_1'
Merge records
Save edits
Select * where fieldname = 'D2' AND fieldname = 'D2_1'
Merge records
```

And so on for the rest...

There is just one X record for X_1.

Thinking of coding this in ArcPy seems over my knowledge.

So I need to write a code which will do something like this:

"Select a pair of records with the same name and where the second one comes with '_1' suffix and merge them."

Comment: Python stands alone among the thirty or forty languages I've studied and learned in the past 35 years, as the easiest programming language to learn. Instead of fearing ArcPy, it would be easier to take a day to start using it. Coding a Dissolve session to do this is on the order of ten lines of code, most of which can be extracted as a "Copy as a Python snippet" from doing it manually.

Comment: I know, sir. Python is on schedule. Currently in my free time I'm learning JS, Python is right next. I'll look into this. Thank you.